# Best approach to test GWT localization?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a set of GWT UIs, some created directly in Java and others created using UI Binder ui.xml files.

I localized them following the official GWT guidelines (e.g. creating interface extending Messages interface).

I now wonder if there is an easy way to write a unit test to validate that message keys get replaced by the corresponding values from property files?

I guess I could do that using GWTTestCase, but actually I don't need a browser to render the page. Instead, it would be enough to get the raw string output and check with some regex that the messages are present.

Is that possible? Or is it better to test such things in running application like using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Just a note. Besides the important things you are trying to validate, one of the critical points in my project during messages localization tests is to see: if the translated text fits the allocated space. If it's a box of fixed size, overlapping texts don't look nice. And this cannot be checked with unit tests. That's why the manual  review is in to-do list when new locale is added or certain labels/messages are changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Selenium. Checking that the messages are present could be tricky, because in that case you should know the place where the label is located, in which tags. In my opinion, using GWTTestCase makes sense when it comes to testing controllers' behavior. Simple search by value guarantees only presence but not correct placement.

I think, it also makes sense to use those translation properties in the tests, so the strings are not duplicates in the tests.